# Inserting into MySQL - integers - through a parametrised query

Tags: pymysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert 3 integers into one of my tables in MySQL and I'm using a parametrised query. My insertion works perfect if the values are of type VARCHAR but in case if my values are integers, the Python code throws the following error:

> typeerror: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found

My python snippet is as follows:

```
keys = tuple(courier_prod_dict) # unpacking dictionary keys into a tuple
values = tuple(courier_prod_dict.values())
         variable_1, variable_2, variable_3 = keys
    
    insert_query = f"""
    
    INSERT INTO {table_name}
    ({variable_1}, {variable_2}, {variable_3}) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
    
    """

with connect.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(insert_query, values)
    connect.commit()
```

I do not know where I'm going wrong. I tried solutions by researching other answers in stackoverflow but nothing helped so far. I shall be indebted if someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore. I found the problem.

I had extracted one of the values using: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() which returned a dictionary. Hence the problem